# Can I boot a 2015 iMac Mojave OS into FreeDOS from a properly prepared DVD or USB drive?

Tags: imac, startup, iso

In a bit of a jam: My 2015 iMac has just come back from repair for a broken Fusion Drive. Unfortunately, the replacement HDD needs a firmware update, but this was ignored by the repair shop. I'd rather try to resolve this myself than fight it out through the credit card company. Due to the difficulties in accessing iMac's internal hardware, the firmware upgrade must be done *in situ*.

The [firmware upgrade is available from Seagate](https://www.seagate.com/support/kb/barracuda-1tbdisk-platform-firmware-update-223651en/), but it's packaged with `FreeDOS` in a "bootable" ISO format. Seagate even supplied some [instructions for preparing a bootable CD/DVD](https://www.seagate.com/support/kb/how-to-burn-an-iso-image-onto-a-cddvd-rom-201431en/#MacOS), but it seems these instructions are for an older version of macOS. Their instructions didn't work on my 10.14 Mojave system, but I found another approach that seems to have worked:

| Finder Window | Burn Disc |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Unfortunately, there's a bigger issue: While the ISO was burned to the DVD, this DVD isn't recognized by the system as a 'Startup Disk'; it isn't presented as an option after a Restart when the <kbd>option</kbd> key is depressed. I have also [tried making a bootable USB drive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick?_ga=2.190828974.429803735.1668245635-2129123856.1668245635) using the "Other Procedure" listed there, but the USB drive wasn't presented as an option either.

I tried using `balenaEtcher` to create a bootable USB using the `.dmg` file created with `hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ~/path/to/target.img ~/path/to/Barracuda-ALL-GRCC4H.iso`. This also failed, but Etcher gave a potentially useful error message shown in the screenshot below.

##### How do I boot my iMac into FreeDOS so I can install the firmware upgrade on my HDD?

[image]

Comment: This sounds similar to my 'fun & games' with a Samsung SSD update. Eventually the only way I got it to work was use an older 'windows-capable' [BIOS not EFI] PC with a CD drive. I also had to format the drive NTFS for it to work, then back again to Mac afterwards. I wish you luck & hope someone has some better news :))

Comment: Could you possibly install Windows on the internal SSD and run the software from Windows?

Comment: "the replacement HDD needs a firmware update" Is that 'needs' to make it work, or 'needs' because one is available? What behaviour does it change for a Mac?

Comment: @Tetsujin: I've got an old Windows 7 PC; problem is getting the HDD out of the iMac - adhesive foam, risk of breakage of the fragile display, etc - the "access" is the only reason I outsourced this repair.

Comment: @DavidAnderson: I don't know what that entails... I've still got an old Win 7 install CD around here somewhere... I wonder if that would work? I'm still [searching for solutions](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=freedos+install+on+macos&t=ffab&atb=v296-1&ia=web), but this looks to be a very steep climb for me.

Comment: @Gilby: Good question - I've wondered the same thing. The guy at the repair shop - who knew of the firmware issue & decided to leave it for me - has speculated that the firmware may be responsible for another issue with their "repair": "the fan running continuously at full speed".  I don't buy that, but DriveDx classified the drive as "FAILING", and I wondered if the firmware might have caused that. When I asked him about this, he said I couldn't trust DriveDx - they used a commercial app which said the drive was OK. I've installed & run `smartctl` - it reports some "odd things"...

Comment: @Gilby:   ... such as: "`Self-test execution status:      (  25) The self-test routine was aborted by the host.`". I've not had time to research all of the smartctl output, but it doesn't look encouraging; e.g. `1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   095   094   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       32912728`. This HDD was mine - I sent it to the repair shop with my iMac; they agreed to "evaluate the health of the drive, and to use it only if it was in good condition - otherwise, replace it with a new one". It seems they didn't do that, but they claim they did... I hate this kind of stuff.

Comment: "fan running at full speed" sounds like they didn't connect temperature sensor properly.  You might be able to work around this in software. I don't buy the might be firmware answer. Sorry to say, this sounds like a "not quite good enough" repair shop

Comment: To install your drive, I would think one would need a thermal sensor such as [this one](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/DIDIMACHDD12/). Do you know if such a device was installed? Also, you can download from Microsoft and install Windows 10 without a product key for free on a trial basis. If you have Mojave installed, then you can easily download the Windows Support Software (the drivers) from Apple. You can install using a USB flash drive.

Comment: @DavidAnderson: Exactly... I discussed that very part with the repair shop before I sent it in. It was my understanding that the sensor would be replaced if necessary... so I don't know what happened or why that wasn't done. Wrt Windows: Is there a procedure I can follow to do this??

Comment: @Gilby: Worse than that - they didn't connect it at all!  Wrt quality and overall experience, I'm not at all pleased with this outcome. In retrospect, I would have been better off doing it myself - following instructions at [IFIXIT](https://www.ifixit.com/Device/iMac_Intel). I never expected perfection, but this has been v. disappointing.

Comment: The original HDD has the sensor builtin which can not be removed from the HDD. If you remove the HDD, you remove the sensor. The replacement HDD has no sensor, therefore you have to purchase the sensor separately. The sensor is attached by tape to the outside of the replacement drive. So when you say "replaced if necessary", my response is "of course you have to replace the sensor, unless the original HDD has be replaced before with a third party drive".

Comment: As for instructions, would you be installing Windows to replace macOS on the SSD? Or would you try for a dual boot arrangement? How large is the SSD?

Comment: @DavidAnderson: re "replaced if necessary": Yes, but I wasn't sure the HDD would have to be replaced when I shipped it for repair. In fact, I was under the impression that only the SSD part of the Fusion Drive would have to be replaced. ----------->  Re installing Windows: AFAICS, the **only** reason for having Windows would be to get the HDD firmware updated. After the Firmware update, I wouldn't need Windows; my idea was to restore my system as it is now - Mojave would be the only OS.  <<<.>>>  What's your confidence level that this bootable fw upgrade ISO is actually bootable in Win 10/11?

Comment: I as working off the assumption the `.iso` can not be used, because this requires FreeDOS to BIOS boot and 2015 iMacs do not have a BIOS. I assume once Windows is installed you would use the `.exe` file instead of the `.iso` file. I read about the `.exe` option in the instructions given in [your link](https://www.seagate.com/support/kb/barracuda-1tbdisk-platform-firmware-update-223651en/).

Comment: @DavidAnderson: Oh of course! I've ignored the Windows instructions up until now, and only just read them :)  It's very interesting reading [this document](https://www.seagate.com/support/kb/firmware-update-utility-instructions-and-faq-004559en/)... as I read this, it seems that the `.exe` package contains GRUB, and a version of the Linux kernel. All that said, it seems to me there may still be risks running on a new-ish Windows... whaddya' think?